# using correct -l -L and -I flags with cc still leads to undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld, cc

I'm working with a Makefile that issues the following command:

```sh
cc -g -O -I/opt/local/include -lsndfile -lm -lpvoc -L/opt/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/   -c -o fileio.o fileio.c
```

followed by eventually:

```sh
cc -o plainpv -g -O -I/opt/local/include -lsndfile -lm -lpvoc -L/opt/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  plainpv.o -L../PVC_LIB -lsndfile -lm -lpvoc -L/opt/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

but that results in the following error:

```
../PVC_LIB/libpvoc.a(fileio.o): In function `getInputFileDataToSetOutputChannels':
/home/meeshkan-abel/Downloads/PVCplus.Beta.Public.Distribution.5-25-2017/PVC_LIB/fileio.c:63: undefined reference to `sf_open'
/home/meeshkan-abel/Downloads/PVCplus.Beta.Public.Distribution.5-25-2017/PVC_LIB/fileio.c:168: undefined reference to `sf_seek'
```

even though both of these functions are in `libsndfile`. I'm wondering why, even though `libsndfile` is linked when building `fileio` and when building `plainpv`, there are still `undefined reference` errors.  Usually I see these when forgetting to link to a library, but it seems like the linking is correct here.  Any thoughts on where to investigate? Thanks!

Comment: The first command is not a linking command, it is just a *compilation* (-c).

Comment: and for the second, the references are filled left-to-right

Comment: the `.o` file is on the *right* of `-lsndfile` in the linking command, unused in the compilation command.